# Explode a pandas row into multiple rows while dividing

Tags: python, pandas

I'm not sure how to word this.

I have a situation where I have daily quantities that I need to evenly split into 3 different shifts.

**Example**
***Original DataFrame***

| product# | day | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan 1 | 30 |
| 1 | Jan 2 | 30 |
| 2 | Jan 2 | 60 |

***Desired Result Data Frame***

| product# | day | quantity | shift |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan 1 | 10 | 1 |
| 1 | Jan 1 | 10 | 2 |
| 1 | Jan 1 | 10 | 3 |
| 2 | Jan 2 | 20 | 1 |
| 2 | Jan 2 | 20 | 2 |
| 2 | Jan 2 | 20 | 3 |

I have a working version that is just the easy pd.iterrows() version but i'm wondering if its possible to do it via the explode function or something like you can with strings here. [How to separate string into multiple rows in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52575290/how-to-separate-string-into-multiple-rows-in-pandas)

edit: The table markdown is working on preview but on on result :/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the **explode** function in pandas, since explode is primarily designed for handling **lists** or **Series** of values within a DataFrame, you'll need to first create a "**shifts**" column with the quantities split into separate rows for each shift.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create the original DataFrame
data = {'product#': [1, 2], 'day': ['Jan 1', 'Jan 2'], 'quantity': [30, 60]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Calculate the quantity per shift
shifts = 3
df['quantity_per_shift'] = df['quantity'] // shifts

# Create a new DataFrame with shifted quantities
shifted_df = df.explode('quantity_per_shift')

# Assign shift numbers
shifted_df['shift'] = shifted_df.groupby('product#').cumcount() + 1

# Drop the temporary column
shifted_df.drop(columns='quantity_per_shift', inplace=True)

print(shifted_df)
```

Comment: This works great, how would it change tho If i make a product on multiple days?

| product# | day | quantity |
|---|---|---|
| 1 | Jan 1 | 30 |
| 1 | Jan 2 | 30 |
| 2 | Jan 2 | 60 |   

i would still want to split by day, i just extend the group by to a multi index right?

Comment: @inzikind yes! shifted_df['shift'] = shifted_df.groupby(['product#', 'day']).cumcount() + 1